# Catia V5 Dynamic Hidden Line Removal With Macro Please Help Me

Tags: vba, macros, catia

[In here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rw4n.png) I try to run the customize view-Dynamic Hidden Line Removal with catscript. I try to use Macro-Start Recording,but it doesnt find it. Do you know How can I solve it?

The recording code is;

Dim specsAndGeomWindow1 As SpecsAndGeomWindow
Set specsAndGeomWindow1 =CATIA.ActiveWindow

Dim viewer3D1 As Viewer3D
Set viewer3D1 = specsAndGeomWindow1.ActiveViewer

Dim viewpoint3D1 As Viewpoint3D1
Set viewpoint3D1 = viewer3D1 Viewpoint3D1